# Create config to change the path of the project folder

Tags: php, config

I made a project using php but i have worked inside the root folder without any directory, now i add a new folder because i need to give it to a person but the old paths on the class's are defined to the new ones.

`"..\root\pfc\index.php"` -> New path

`"..\root\index.php`" -> Old path, all the classes path are referenced to here

I think i need a config.php but i don't know which variable i need to use.

I have tried to use `realpath( dirname(__FILE__).'/..');`

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: I didn't create any...

Comment: Then how is it being redirected?

Comment: i use the href of html and send the link to the folder i need